# Python regex findall matching all pairs of words

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I need to make a list of every pair of words sequentially in a string with a regex, the relevant part of the code is this:

```
for word in re.findall(r'\w+\b.*?\w+', text):
```

Now let's take as example the text ***"This is a random text"***, what i want is a list like this:

> **['This is','is a','a random','random text']**

Instead what I'm getting is this:

> **['This is','a random']**

How can i fix this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You said that the words are separated by a random amount of spaces and/or punctuation,
I used `[\s\.]+` for that.

what you are doing wrong here is that you are consuming the second word, what you need is a positive lookahead that match the second word but don't consume it, so it will match it next time.
and because you said it's a massive Text I think using `finditer` is better than `findall` the difference is that it return a generator that produce the same elements returned by `findall`:

```py
import re

text ="""This. is a random text"""

pattern = re.compile(r'(\w+[\s\.]+)(?=(\w+))')
for match in pattern.finditer(text):
    # rebuild the word
    element = ''.join(match.groups())
    print(element)
```

Ouput:

```
This. is
is a
a random
random text
```

Note that by default positive lookahead is not a capturing group this why a I did this `(?=(\w+))` to capture the word inside it. First group is `(\w+[\s\.]+)`. and I used `join` to rebuild concatenate the groups again.

Comment: Wouldn't \W+ be better than [\s\.] as the punctuation can be anything really: .,;:-_!"£$%&/()=?^ etc?

Comment: This worked perfectly, thank you very very much, i ended up using (\w+\b.*?)(?=(\w+)) instead

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use regex for this task, take a look at this:

```
(\w+)\s+(?=(\w+))
```

[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/WbEZGF/1)

The trick is to use **positive lookahead** for the second word and capture it within a group. In order to output the resulting pairs, combine the result of Group 1 and Group 2 matches.

Answer (score 0):

Typically I don't think the same RegEx allows for overlapping search results. What you might want to do instead is find the intermediate spaces and find the words that are just before and just after the space.

Comment: How could i do that? Iterating over the "intermediate spaces" result would take forever, the string in question is massive, to do anything with iteration i should work with threads and such, its a string hundreds of Megabytes long.

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to used regex for this case you can just use split

```py
st = "This is a random text"
sp = st.split()

result = [f"{w1} {w2}" for w1, w2 in zip(sp, sp[1:])]
print(result)
```

**result**

```
['This is', 'is a', 'a random', 'random text']
```

**Edit**

For large data you can implement generator. like pseudo code below

```py
def get_pair_from_large_text():
    tail_of_last_chunk = ""
    while True
        chunk = get_string_chunk_from_source()
        if len(chunk)==0:
            yield f"{words[-2]} {words[-1]}"
            break
        chunk = tail_of_last_chunk[1] + chunk

        words = split(chunk)
        tail_of_last_chunk = words[-2], words[-1]

        for w1, w2 in zip(words[:-1], words[1:-1])
            yield f"{w1} {w2}"
```

Comment: The example text is very basic, the real text has a random amount of spaces and/or punctuation between the words, also iterating would take forever due to the massive size of the string.

Comment: you can create generator do the processing in chunks for large file

Answer (score 0):

But do you really need regex?
You can do that without regex

```
L1 = line.split(' ')
L2 = L1[1:].append(' ')
Result = [' '.join(a,b) for a,b in zip(L1,L2)]
```

Using Regex but the result is not in order

```
>>> pattern1 = re.compile(r"(\w+\s+\w+)")
>>> pattern2 = re.compile(r"(\s+\w+\s+\w+)")
>>> l1 = re.findall(pattern1, line)
>>> l2 =[x.strip() for x in re.findall(pattern2, line)]
>>> l1
['This is', 'a random']
>>> l2
['is a', 'random text']
>>> l1 + l2
['This is', 'a random', 'is a', 'random text']
```

Comment: Your L1 has a typo

Comment: Fixed. Thanks @MyNamelsCaleb

Comment: Please check my reply to the comment of Dev Khadka

Answer (score 0):

A regular expression isn't necessary here.

You can use [`itertools.pairwise`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.pairwise) if you're on Python 3.10 to get all the bigrams. It will output an iterable of 2-tuples, with one word per element in the tuple. You can then use `" ".join()` to turn each tuple into a string:

```py
from itertools import pairwise

data = "This is a random text"
print([" ".join(bigram) for bigram in pairwise(data.split(" "))])
```

This outputs:

```py
['This is', 'is a', 'a random', 'random text']
```